# HttpClient, How to send illegal characters in URI string

Tags: java, httpclient

I'd like to come up with some automated tests to validate my servers handling of invalid request URIs. For example, a tester was able to send this as his url using curl on windows:

```
http://127.0.0.1/C:\an\incorrect\path\file.txt
```

I have handling on the server to deal with that, but still want to add tests if possible. Tried to do it with HttpClient but HttpClient doesn't like the invalid characters ;)

```
// Run client
                String Url = targetHost + filePath + fileName;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);

                // run test
                InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + LusConstants.DIR_SEPERATOR + fileName),-1);
                reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                reqEntity.setChunked(chunked);
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Exception from HttpClient:

```
aused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 39: http://127.0.0.1:8080//a/deeper/path/an\incorrect\path\file.txt
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\i escapes. The result is a tab.

An url may only hold printable US-ASCII code.
There is a % notation for other codes

use for backslash

%5c = "\"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can write your own raw http client, so there is no URL validation at your client side. Check this out:

http://code.joejag.com/2012/how-to-send-a-raw-http-request-via-java/